# html5 + CSS3 center page text by header banner

Tags: html, css

I am trying to move from old html styled with tables, to html5 styled with CSS, but I have problems:

[<kbd>codepen Demo</kbd>](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/lKzis)

You can see that, text is aligned to the edge of the page, and I want it aligned to the edge of the header banner.

I cant figure out, how to do that? without using tables.

Also, please note, that the .article:nth-child(odd) CSS selector, somehow aligns the odd elements to the left, and not to the right... I dont understand why.

Thanks!

Comment: Give .article a width

Comment: `nth` does NOT work with classes unless all of the siblings have the same class.

Comment: By splitting out the style and putting it in the CSS section, it seems to work for me.

Comment: Do you mean aligned to the text inside the banners? on which sides?

Comment: This is not related to your question, but an observation from your code. If you have blocks in different languages in your code, you can also use the standard HTML attribute `lang` (ex: `<article ... lang='he'>`) and select using CSS2 `:lang()` pseudo-class (ex: `:lang('ru') {...}`) Then you can apply text direction properties in one place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your content have the same width as a header, but you have image inside header which have a little less width than 100% of site, so what u need to do is add some width for `article` something like this:

```
.article {
   display: block;
   margin: auto;
   width: 900px;
}
```

[<kbd>codepen Demo</kbd>](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pkoCc)

Answer (score 1):

For example

[<kbd>codepen Demo</kbd>](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bfgmu)

```
.article {
     width: 1024px;
}
```

To center the .articles you need to set a width. Also you might want to consider getting rid of

```
<div align="center">
```

It's deprecated in html5

Answer (score 1):

The best way to create a fixed width website is to add a containing div:

Simply add a fixed width div around all your current code.

```
#Wrap{width:1024px;}
```

.

```
<body>
  <div id="Wrap">
    ...
    /* rest of website */
    ...
  </div>
</body>
```

[<kbd>codepen Demo</kbd>](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/AFeGk)

---

### CLEAN EXAMPLE

**HTML**

```
<div id="Wrap">
  <div id="Head"></div>
  <div id="Body"></div>
  <div id="Foot"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#Wrap{
  width:1024px; /*Your desired page width*/
  margin:0 auto; /*Center your wrapper on the page*/
}
#Head{
  width:100%; /*Fill the width of the wrapper*/
}
#Body{
  width:100%; /*Fill the width of the wrapper*/
}
#Foot{
  width:100%; /*Fill the width of the wrapper*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to write css to style the page correctly:

[<kbd>codepen Demo</kbd>](http://codepen.io/jonigiuro/pen/qIilf)

```
div {
  text-align: center;
}
```